# Using docx4j to convert .docx to .pdf

Tags: java, pdf, docx4j

I'm trying to convert .docx files to .pdf files. Now I have the following code:

```
class DocxToPdf {
    fun convert(inputFileLocation: FileInputStream, outputFileLocation: FileOutputStream) {
        val wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(inputFileLocation)
        val mainDocumentPart = wordMLPackage.mainDocumentPart
        Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, outputFileLocation)

        outputFileLocation.flush()
        outputFileLocation.close()
    }
}
```

These are the versions:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-Internal</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-MOXy</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I run it, I'm only getting an empty pdf file. I also get the following stack trace:

org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:767)
at com.abnamro.edc.loki.domain.adapters.conversion.docx4j.DocxToPdf.convert(DocxToPdf.kt:12)
at com.abnamro.edc.domain.adapters.conversion.docx4j.DocxToPdfTest.Convert a docx file successfully$loki_app(DocxToPdfTest.kt:20)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:747)
... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.getFopConfigContext()Ljakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext;
at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.getFopFactoryBuilder(FORendererApacheFOP.java:286)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.getFopFactoryBuilder(FORendererApacheFOP.java:271)
... 76 more

What should I do more?

Comment: do you have docx4j-export-fo and the fop deps on your classpath?  is there a stack trace?

Comment: I have the docx4j-export-fo in my pom as a dependency. Unfortunately I don't have a stack trace. The operation seems to go correctly, apart from an empty pdf file being generated.

Comment: I found a stack trace. Added it to the post.

Comment: What version of docx4j are you using?

Comment: I've added the versions in the post. They should be the most recent.

Comment: You have 3 different and conflicting docx4j-JAXB-* implementations.  Choose one and only one (eg docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl 11.4.6), then please confirm stack trace still occurs with the same line numbers.

Comment: I've checked and was able to make it work with docx4j-JAXB-Internal version 8.3.4. Still getting the same stack trace tho. [org.doc.Docx4J] (main) null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Also having an empty file as a result. It seems to work when I use version 8 of both docx4j-export-fo and docx4j-JAXB-Internal, except for the pdf conversion giving a bad result. E.g. images being put horizontal instead of vertical and off page.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't mix v8 and v11 jars.  Quality of the conversion is a separate issue; see https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/09/office-pptxxlsxdocx-to-pdf-to-in-docx4j-8-2-3/

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, you should use  one and only one of JXB dependencies:
[image]

Update your pom.xml to only keep `docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl` then retry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
        <version>11.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
        <version>11.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```